# Error URI malformed when running react application on mac

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-start

I am trying to run React app locally.

When running `npm run dev` I get error

```
 vite v2.6.14 dev server running at:

  > Local: http://localhost:3000/
  > Network: use `--host` to expose

  ready in 182ms.

/Users/markoz/Work/Razvoj/Graphs/kenstack-designer/kenstack-designer/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e0fe87f8.js:56882
        let url = decodeURI(removeTimestampQuery(req.url)).replace(NULL_BYTE_PLACEHOLDER, '\0');
                  ^

URIError: URI malformed
    at decodeURI (<anonymous>)
    at viteTransformMiddleware (/Users/markoz/Work/Razvoj/Graphs/kenstack-designer/kenstack-designer/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e0fe87f8.js:56882:19)
    at call (/Users/markoz/Work/Razvoj/Graphs/kenstack-designer/kenstack-designer/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e0fe87f8.js:45568:7)
    at next (/Users/markoz/Work/Razvoj/Graphs/kenstack-designer/kenstack-designer/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e0fe87f8.js:45512:5)
    at /Users/markoz/Work/Razvoj/Graphs/kenstack-designer/kenstack-designer/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e0fe87f8.js:56525:28
    at viteServePublicMiddleware (/Users/markoz/Work/Razvoj/Graphs/kenstack-designer/kenstack-designer/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e0fe87f8.js:56564:9)
    at call (/Users/markoz/Work/Razvoj/Graphs/kenstack-designer/kenstack-designer/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e0fe87f8.js:45568:7)
    at next (/Users/markoz/Work/Razvoj/Graphs/kenstack-designer/kenstack-designer/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e0fe87f8.js:45512:5)
    at next (/Users/markoz/Work/Razvoj/Graphs/kenstack-designer/kenstack-designer/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e0fe87f8.js:45490:14)
    at next (/Users/markoz/Work/Razvoj/Graphs/kenstack-designer/kenstack-designer/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e0fe87f8.js:45490:14)

Node.js v17.4.0
```

I don't have `.npmrc` on my system folder, but I have one inside the project.

How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

remove "%PUBLIC_URL%" in "public/index.html".

https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/6482

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, I manually installed `vite` to a react project and got this same error.

My solution was to replace "%PUBLIC_URL%" with "public" in the URLs inside the index.html file.