# migration vu-cli to vite

Tags: vuejs3, vite, vue-cli

I migrate vue-cli to vite with project on vue3. when i start my project i have this error

```
5:54:44 PM [vite] Internal server error: URI malformed
      at decodeURI (<anonymous>)
      at viteTransformMiddleware (/home/20103347/Documents/iky/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6e2fe41e.js:57512:19)
      at call (/home/20103347/Documents/iky/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6e2fe41e.js:44131:7)
      at next (/home/20103347/Documents/iky/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6e2fe41e.js:44075:5)
      at /home/20103347/Documents/iky/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6e2fe41e.js:49249:28
      at viteServePublicMiddleware (/home/20103347/Documents/iky/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6e2fe41e.js:49761:9)
      at call (/home/20103347/Documents/iky/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6e2fe41e.js:44131:7)
      at next (/home/20103347/Documents/iky/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6e2fe41e.js:44075:5)
      at next (/home/20103347/Documents/iky/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6e2fe41e.js:44053:14)
      at next (/home/20103347/Documents/iky/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6e2fe41e.js:44053:14)
```

How can i fix it ?

i would like fix this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error URI malformed when running react application on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72396236/error-uri-malformed-when-running-react-application-on-mac)